# Why TypeScript cannot determine the return type depending on argument?

Tags: typescript

I have this function which returns a string when encoding is specified. Otherwise it returns a `Buffer`,

```js
import { createHash } from "crypto";

// returns a string when encoding is specified; otherwise it returns Buffer
const sha256 = (data: string | string[], encoding?: BinaryToTextEncoding) => {
  const hash = createHash("sha256");
  if (Array.isArray(data)) {
    data.forEach((s) => hash.update(s));
  } else {
    hash.update(data);
  }
  if (encoding) {
    // return string
    return hash.digest(encoding);
  }
  // return Buffer
  return hash.digest();
};

// why hashed is not string but string | Buffer
const hashed = sha256(["a", "b"], "hex");
```

At the last line, I'm expecting the `hashed` is a string because I have passed in the encoding `hex`. However, TypeScript is still see `hashed` as `string | Buffer`.

The issue was solved using [function overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) pointed by @apokryfos

```js
function sha256(data: string, encoding: BinaryToTextEncoding): string;

// eslint-disable-next-line no-redeclare
function sha256(data: string[], encoding: BinaryToTextEncoding): string;

// eslint-disable-next-line no-redeclare
function sha256(data: string[]): Buffer;

// eslint-disable-next-line no-redeclare
function sha256(data: string): Buffer;

// eslint-disable-next-line no-redeclare
function sha256(data: string | string[], encoding?: BinaryToTextEncoding) {
  // the same function implementation as shown above ...
}
```

Notes:

- I have to disable ESLint's rule [no-redeclare](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-redeclare/).
- I have to redeclare the function using function declaration instead of arrow function

Comment: So, what is your question? Do you want to understand why it doesn't infer the return type or do you want a solution on how to make typescript infer the type?

Comment: You need to use [function overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) TS won't infer overloads for you

Comment: Thanks, @apokryfos for pointing me to the function overloads. It would be nice if you can reply with "answer" so that I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a typical use case for [function overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads)

```
function sha256(data: string | string[], encoding: string): Buffer;
function sha256(data: string | string[]): string;
function sha256(data: string | string[], encoding?: string): string|Buffer {
      if (encoding) {
            return Buffer.from('abc');
      }
      return 'abc';
};

const hashed = sha256(["a", "b"], "hex");
      // ^?  Buffer

const hashed2 = sha256(["a", "b"]);
      // ^? string
```

Note: While you are correct in noticing you need to disable the [`no-redeclare`](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-redeclare/) rule, however the red notice on the top of that page does seem to indicate that you should not be using this rule in TypeScript anyway. As an additional aside using this approach does require you to use `function` rather than lambdas.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&moduleResolution=99&module=199#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEIFcY2sg3gX2QHoi0IE50BnFYMAciuQFtgqrQBzZAC2hQBQAmOhAIwwAPYhkVHnABMAVgBsACgAmcMHABcssFC7IAPgaMhOAbQC6AGmQQxkjV31VDXAJT6MWaADcwqLiUjJyiqqa2nrmxmYeFtY2PnGWQSJiEtKy8srqWjrunpamackOTgguXAD8xUmpiVwmfthQeALI3T3AMMhqVTWWXp094xNQEGDoUDJt0AB0MFCSzGr0cABGCPReQRPI%20F2T07Mymzv0QfhBAtUgHrxwchAayAC8uZHqVgBEcD%20Dj%20Wz%209mQfz4AA8-vsTuMSMgAHq1IQPJ7yV4aBSfb75NT-QHA0EpA4TREooA)

There's also an alternative way to implement overloads but that (for some reason) requires some more casting to work, however allows you to use Lambdas and will not trip the `no-redeclare` rule, if those are strict requirements:

```
interface Sha256 {
    (data: string | string[], encoding: string): Buffer;
    (data: string | string[]): string;
}

const sha256: Sha256 = (data: string | string[], encoding?: string) => {
    if (encoding) {
        return {} as any;
    }
    return 'abc' as any;
}

const res1 = sha256('a');
      //^? string
const res2= sha256('a','b');
      //^? Buffer
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&moduleResolution=99&module=199#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEIFcY2sg3gXwChDRJZEUBlACzgCYBWANj0OXeQAoATOMOAFzIAzmCigA5sgA%20IsZIDaAXQA0yCCAQB7bpKGjxICQEohGLNADcbDjz6C5hqbIOKlpx5OtFC2kKJFaRiYhGnpmZABeLl5%20fXkjGU8jZTUNbV0jAH54p2MogD5WDmRgGC50nUl83BsS9igIMHQoEDx8ZDhhTpAAT2sSohLG5tbkAHI4ACMEcc7uuD7vYj8AxuEARijA8KZOSfHjAfqAehOAPSzfLX8wZHW6aOEg5n24cZVxqcPjkrPLoA)

Comment: This is a lot more cleaner code to me @apokryfos!
The only thing which I'm still figuring out is two return statements "as any". TypeScript seems not able to know the return type (string or Buffer) without returning "as any"?